# matplotlib add_subplot odd number of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that `add_subplot()` makes a squared grid of plots, I'm doing that with a 4x4 grid but I need one more. How can I do the same but with an odd number of plots and make it look like this?
[image: odd grid]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there are very sophisticated solutions involving e.g. the [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) module, which is a very neat tool in many cases.

However when having a rather simple requirement as here, you can still use `add_subplot()` as usual.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(323)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(325)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(224)
```

[image]

---

Edit: In order to make the axes `ax1`, `ax2`, and `ax3` share the x axis, you can use the `sharex` argument to `add_subplot`. Optionally, turning the xlabels off should then be done by setting them invisible, as otherwise all three axes would loose their labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(321)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(323, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(325, sharex=ax1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(224)

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

Comment: I'm going to pick this answer because its extreme simplicity. No need to add more code than the one I already have.

Comment: Is there a way to make only the three subplots of the left share the x axis?

Comment: Short and precise

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `gridspec` submodule:

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=6, ncols=2)

ax11 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, 0])
ax21 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 0])
ax31 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:, 0])
ax12 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:3, 1])
ax22 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:, 1])
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Potential option is the following

```
fig = plt.figure()                               
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (2, 0), rowspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (4, 0), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (0, 1), rowspan=3)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 2), (3, 1), rowspan=3)
```