# Pandas subplot layout not working in this case

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I was plotting some scatter plot of mpg dataset from the seaborn library. I was wondering if it is possible to plot the odd number of subplots in python?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
df.groupby('origin').plot.scatter(x='cylinders',y='mpg',subplots=True,layout=(2,2))
```

This gives 4,1 plots not 2,2 plots:
[image]

Is there a way of obtaining 3 subplolts for usa,europe and japan with label names 
like shown below in more easier way?

This is a long way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
g = df.groupby('origin')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8, 4))
for i, (g_name, g_data) in enumerate(g): # axes.flat also works
    ax = g_data.plot.scatter(x='cylinders', y='mpg', ax=axes.flatten()[i], title=g_name)

plt.tight_layout()
fig.delaxes(axes[1][1])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib add_subplot odd number of plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025187/matplotlib-add-subplot-odd-number-of-plots)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694501/delete-a-subplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`delaxes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.delaxes.html):

```
fig.delaxes(axes[1][1])
```